# Angular 4 Currency Pipe with Input Text Field

Tags: angular, angular4-forms

I have an input field that I would like to display proper currency formatting upon data entry from the web user (USD)...

A little background on this, the previous input mask I was using would start backward (Example: If a user enters 10, rather than showing $10, it shows 0.10... so if the user wanted to display $100.00, a user would have to enter 1 and 4 zeros in order to achieve this...)

Jumping forward to where I'm at today... I want to be able to enter "10" in the input field and then have it display in real time in the input field as the proper USD currency format: $10.00.

```
<div class="col-6 col-sm-6 col-md-2 col-lg-1 form-group" *ngIf="configuration.is_item_price_and_total_visible;">
     <mat-form-field floatLabel="never">
       <input matInput type="text" placeholder="Price" [(ngModel)]="selected_item_price | currency:'USD' (ngModelChange)="selected_item_price=$event" name="price">
     </mat-form-field>
</div>
```

Comment: how can you ensure that *1 and 4 zeros* it must be `100`? what if he needs to enter `10000`? Do you mean that add trailing `.00` after user entered value?

Comment: https://angular.io/api/common/CurrencyPipe

Comment: Per my user requirements, if user enters 100 without any decimal points, the assumed output value would be $100.00 -- if user enters 10000, the assumed output value would be: $10,000.00 - are we saying the same thing?

Comment: Bonci, in the few minutes that it took you to post this link to currencypipe... I can assure you I spent hours upon hours prior to posting this... and yes... I have already visited this URL and still have the issue.

Comment: So just to clarify something... if I print out {{selected_item_price | currency}} -- it's working exactly as it should... the issue is that it's not happening IN the input itself... It is not working when I try to put the pipe on the ngModel using the two way binding method above - I get an error message.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use Template expression operators(pipe, save navigator) within template statement. i.e. [ngModel]="selected_item_price | currency:'USD'"

try parsing the input value property like

```
<div class="col-6 col-sm-6 col-md-2 col-lg-1 form-group" *ngIf="configuration.is_item_price_and_total_visible;">
      <mat-form-field floatLabel="never">
       <input matInput type="text" placeholder="Price" [value]="selected_item_price| currency:'USD':true:'1.0-2'" [(ngModel)]="selected_item_price" name="price">
      </mat-form-field>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to split the binding into a one-way binding `[ngModel]="selected_item_price | currency:'USD'"` and an event binding `(ngModelChange)="selected_item_price=$event"` because pipes works only with one-way binding.

```
<mat-form-field floatLabel="never">
  <input matInput type="text" placeholder="Price" [ngModel]="selected_item_price | currency:'USD'" (ngModelChange)="selected_item_price=$event" name="price">
</mat-form-field>
```

You can use also `(blur)="selected_item_price = $event.target.value"` and `(keyup)="selected_item_price = $event.target.value"` events to update `selected_item_price` after removing `()` from `ngModel`